# Django model save() not inserting new record

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have a problem that the save method on a many to many model is not inserting into the database:

```
try:
    dnpg = Device_Name_Product_Group_XREF.objects.get(
        device_name=dn,
        product_group = product_group
    )
except Device_Name_Product_Group_XREF.DoesNotExist:
    dnpg = Device_Name_Product_Group_XREF(
        device_name=dn,
        product_group=product_group
    )

dnpg.save()

# this prints: {'product_group': 1992L, 'device_name': 6481L}
print model_to_dict(dnpg)
```

The code above should insert a record into the XREF table with values (1992,6481), but it does not. Here are my model definitions:

```
class Device_Name_Product_Group_XREF(models.Model):
    device_name = models.ForeignKey(Device_Name, primary_key=True, to_field = "id", db_column="DEVICE_NAME_ID")
    product_group = models.ForeignKey(Product_Group, primary_key=True, to_field = "id", db_column="PRODUCT_GROUP_ID")

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'ADMIN_DEVICE_NAMES_PRODUCT_GROUP_XREF'
        managed = False
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get any error? can you show the full traceback?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) instead of `try`/`except` construction.